# Laravel | PHP convert text file content into Array

Tags: php, laravel

I have text file in storage folder of my Laravel project, which has content like that:

```
<CipherResponse>:Register-Failed,Channel:WEB,From Account:XXXXXXXXXXXX8400,Data:{result=Account Number Already Registered., status=1}

<CipherResponse>:Register-Success,Channel:WEB,Username:abc_123123,From Account:XXXXXXXXXXXX7500,Data:{result=Success., status=0}

<CipherResponse>:Transfer-Failed,Channel:WEB,From Account:XXXXXXXXXXXX0100,To Account:XXXXXXXXXXXXX3321,Amount:1,Data:{result=Failed., status=1}

<CipherResponse>:Transfer-Success,Channel:WEB,From Account:XXXXXXXXXXXX0100,To Account:XXXXXXXXXXXXX3325,Amount:1,Data:{result=Success., data={stan=234324, responseCode=00, rrn=456456546}, status=0, timestamp=1593514332078}
```

[image]

while:

```
<CipherResponse> is the key to get log line 
Register is the activity key to search 
Success is the status of the request
```

and

```
Data:{result=Account Number Already Registered., status=1} response should be in new inside a main array.
```

Here is my code:

```
        $path = storage_path() . "/app/public/Issue_Update.txt";
        $file = File::get($path);

        $array = array();

        foreach (explode("<CipherResponse>:", $file) as $key=>$line){
            $array[$key] = $line;
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($array);
        echo "</pre>";
```

And response,

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => Register-Failed,Channel:WEB,From Account:XXXXXXXXXXXX8400,Data:{result=Account Number Already Registered., status=1}


    [2] => Register-Success,Channel:WEB,Username:abc_123123,From Account:XXXXXXXXXXXX7500,Data:{result=Success., status=0}


    [3] => Transfer-Failed,Channel:WEB,From Account:XXXXXXXXXXXX0100,To Account:XXXXXXXXXXXXX3321,Amount:1,Data:{result=Failed., status=1}


    [4] => Transfer-Success,Channel:WEB,From Account:XXXXXXXXXXXX0100,To Account:XXXXXXXXXXXXX3325,Amount:1,Data:{result=Success., data={stan=234324, responseCode=00, rrn=456456546}, status=0, timestamp=1593514332078}
)
```

And the response i wan to generate after reading the text file, as i have provided sample above,

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Register
            [1] => Failed
            [2] => Channel:WEB
            [3] => XXXXXXXXXXXX8400
            [4] => [
                result=Account Number Already Registered,
                status=1
            ]

        )
        [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Register
            [1] => Success
            [2] => Channel:WEB
            [3] => Username:abc_123123
            [4] => From Account:XXXXXXXXXXXX7500
            [5] => [
                result=Success,
                status=0
            ]

        )
        [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Transfer
            [1] => Failed
            [2] => Channel:WEB
            [3] => From Account:XXXXXXXXXXXX7500
            [4]=> To Account:XXXXXXXXXXXXX3321
            [5]=> Amount:1
            [6] => [
                result=Failed,
                status=1
            ]

        )
        [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Transfer
            [1] => Failed
            [2] => Channel:WEB
            [3] => From Account:XXXXXXXXXXXX7500
            [4]=> To Account:XXXXXXXXXXXXX3321
            [5]=> Amount:1
            [6] => [
                result=Success,
                [data] => [
                    stan=234324, 
                    responseCode=00, 
                    rrn=456456546
                 ],
                  status=0, timestamp=1593514332078
                
            ]

        )
)
```

I have to read this file and convert its content to Array. How i can achieve this, can anyone help?

Comment: What type of file is it? It looks like xml but im missing the clossing tags

Comment: it is a text fiile

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Laravel has a build in function for this, but you could read the file line by line with `fgets()` function https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fgets.asp

And then use explode or rexeg and some if statements to get the data you whant of that line

EDIT:
Now you have to use regex I think. `explode(',')` will not work I guess because there is also a `,` in your data json string

Comment: Can you provide any example?

Comment: I tried to make the right regex on https://regex101.com/ but it didn't work well

Comment: Your welcome, if you or some one else can write the right regex it can be easy. Else you have to use explode and use alot of if else statements and use `strpos()` `strlen` and  `substr` functions like that to get the right data. In the regex tester i used `(.*?),` you will get almost all data but on the `Data:` it breaks

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example will help you I guess.

```
    $filecont = file_get_contents(storage_path('app/public/Issue_Update.txt'));
    $filecont = str_replace("\r\n", ",", $filecont);
    
    $array = array();

    foreach (explode("<CipherResponse>:", $filecont) as $key=>$line){
        if(!empty($line)){
            $array[$key] = array_filter(explode(",", $line));
        }
    }
    
    array_filter($array);
    
    \dd($array);
```

using this method you will get

```
array:5 [
  0 => array:1 [
    0 => "﻿"
  ]
  1 => array:5 [
    0 => "Register-Failed"
    1 => "Channel:WEB"
    2 => "From Account:XXXXXXXXXXXX8400"
    3 => "Data:{result=Account Number Already Registered."
    4 => " status=1}"
  ]
  2 => array:6 [
    0 => "Register-Success"
    1 => "Channel:WEB"
    2 => "Username:abc_123123"
    3 => "From Account:XXXXXXXXXXXX7500"
    4 => "Data:{result=Success."
    5 => " status=0}"
  ]
  3 => array:7 [
    0 => "Transfer-Failed"
    1 => "Channel:WEB"
    2 => "From Account:XXXXXXXXXXXX0100"
    3 => "To Account:XXXXXXXXXXXXX3321"
    4 => "Amount:1"
    5 => "Data:{result=Failed."
    6 => " status=1}"
  ]
  4 => array:11 [
    0 => "Transfer-Success"
    1 => "Channel:WEB"
    2 => "From Account:XXXXXXXXXXXX0100"
    3 => "To Account:XXXXXXXXXXXXX3325"
    4 => "Amount:1"
    5 => "Data:{result=Success."
    6 => " data={stan=234324"
    7 => " responseCode=00"
    8 => " rrn=456456546}"
    9 => " status=0"
    10 => " timestamp=1593514332078}"
  ]
]
```

you can do lots of tweaks to fix it this is just a simple example to understand.